# how to use class name generated in while loop

Tags: jquery

I want to use the class name generated in while loop for my jquery function.

```
while()
{
<select class='one'>
</select>
<select class='two'>
</select>  
$(function(){

$('.one').on('change',function(){
    var selIndex= $(".one option:selected").index();

    $(".two option").eq(selIndex).prop('selected', true);
});

});
}
```

Comment: I think you need `$(this).next('.two').find('option').eq(selIndex).prop('selected', true)`

Comment: Why are your HTML and Javascript stay in while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to target relative elements, you can use `this` inside the event handlers to target the changed `select.one`.

```
$(function () {

    $('.one').on('change', function () {
        var selIndex = $(this).find("option:selected").index();
        $(this).next(".two").find('option').eq(selIndex).prop('selected', true);
    });

});
```